# powershell: commands list run ok in CLI, but not in script?

Tags: powershell

I write a small script to launch a ping test + grab Wifi network info and export this is a CSV file.

When launching these commands with copy-past in powershell console it works well
If I save these commands in wifi.ps1 script file and launch this script, it does not update any value

If I remove the while(1) comment for permanent tests, it copies always the same data into the CSV

any idea ?

Thank you

```
    $RegEx=@'
    (?x)
    SSID\s\d+\s:\s(?<SSID>[a-z0-9\-\*\.&_]+)\r\n
    Network\stype\s+:\s(?<NetworkType>\w+)\r\n
    Authentication\s+:\s(?<Authentication>[a-z0-9\-_]+)\r\n
    Encryption\s+:\s(?<Encryption>\w+)\r\n
    BSSID\s1\s+:\s(?<BSSID>(?:\w+:){5}\w+)\r\n
    Signal\s+:\s(?<Signal>\d{1,2})%\r\n
    Radio\stype\s+:\s(?<Radio>[a-z0-9\.]+)\r\n
    Channel\s+:\s(?<Channel>\w+)\r\n
'@ 

$destination = "192.168.0.1"
$delay = 1  

#while (1) {

$test = (Test-Connection -ComputerName $destination -Count 1  | measure-Object -Property ResponseTime -Average).average 
$response = ($test -as [int] ) 
$WiFi = (netsh wlan show  network mode=bssid  | Select-Object  ).Trim() | Out-String 
$Networks  = $WiFi  -split "\r\s+\n" #remove empty line
$Networks  | ForEach {
    If  ($_ -match  $RegEx) {
        $result= [pscustomobject]@{
            TimeStamp = (Get-Date -Format "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss")
            SSID =  $Matches.SSID
            BSSID1 =  $Matches.BSSID
            SignalPercentage = [int]$Matches.Signal
            RadioType = $Matches.Radio
            Channel = $Matches.Channel
            destination = $destination
            ping = $response 
            }
    } 
}
$result | Export-Csv -Path C:\tmp\output.csv -Append

#}
#Start-sleep -seconds $delay
```

Comment: `$Result =` should be outside the loop:  `$result = $Networks | ForEach { If  ($_ -match  $RegEx) { [pscustomobject]@{ ...`, Even better is to prevent the pipeline from stalling and directly pipe each item into the `csv` file: `$Networks | ForEach { ... } | Export-Csv -Path C:\tmp\output.csv -Append`

Comment: if I launch the script wifi.ps1 in  a new powershell, I've an error: PS C:\tmp> .\script.ps1
Export-Csv : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because it is null.
At C:\tmp\wifi1.ps1:36 char:11
+ $result | Export-Csv -Path C:\tmp\output.csv -Append
+           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Export-Csv], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ExportCsvCo
   mmand

Comment: @iRon it works better, but only when I copy-past the script in command line powershell. if launched via a script.PS1 file, it does not work

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated release that works when I copy past in powershell CLI, but not via a script.PS1.

Then by using while(1), I expect CSV file updted every second

Any idea ?

```
$destination = "192.168.0.1"
$delay = 1
#####Don't change below#####
$RegEx=@'
    (?x)
    SSID\s\d+\s:\s(?<SSID>[a-z0-9\-\*\.&_]+)\r\n
    Network\stype\s+:\s(?<NetworkType>\w+)\r\n
    Authentication\s+:\s(?<Authentication>[a-z0-9\-_]+)\r\n
    Encryption\s+:\s(?<Encryption>\w+)\r\n
    BSSID\s1\s+:\s(?<BSSID>(?:\w+:){5}\w+)\r\n
    Signal\s+:\s(?<Signal>\d{1,2})%\r\n
    Radio\stype\s+:\s(?<Radio>[a-z0-9\.]+)\r\n
    Channel\s+:\s(?<Channel>\w+)\r\n
'@ 
#while (1) {

$test = (Test-Connection -ComputerName $destination -Count 1  | measure-Object -Property ResponseTime -Average).average 
$ping_TTL = ($test -as [int] ) 
$WiFi = (netsh wlan show  network mode=bssid  | Select-Object  ).Trim() | Out-String 
$Networks  = $WiFi  -split "\r\s+\n" #remove empty line
$Networks  | ForEach {
    If  ($_ -match  $RegEx) {
            [pscustomobject]@{
            TimeStamp = (Get-Date -Format "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss")
            SSID =  $Matches.SSID
            BSSID1 =  $Matches.BSSID
            SignalPercentage = [int]$Matches.Signal
            RadioType = $Matches.Radio
            Channel = $Matches.Channel
            destination = $destination
            ping = $ping_TTL 
            }
    } 
} | Export-Csv -Path C:\tmp\output.csv -Append


#Start-sleep -seconds $delay
```